# Retrieve Profile Picture with REST

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, rest, ajax

Hi i would like to show the profile pictures of the user that have created the item in a list,

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
      var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>MyListName</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
            <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
            <FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /> \
            <FieldRef Name='Body' /> \
            <FieldRef Name='Created_By' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({ //Ajax call to specific list url, type ,data 

        url: "myListUrl",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: Result, //call to function, Result 
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}); 
//Foreach item in list, append li tag with title attribute
     //   var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li></br>";
function Result(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() { //foreach loop

         var listClass = "list";

         var liHtmlContent = "<div class='"+ listClass +"'>" + "<h2>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</h2>" + "</br>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body") + "</div></br>";

        $(".innerWrap").append(liHtmlContent); //append item content

    });
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You have only posted a lot of code without asking a real question

Comment: I guess he/she don't know how to do it.. :)

Comment: <FieldRef Name='Created_By , How can i populate it with the url of the profile picture?

Comment: i want to append $(".innerWrap").append($(this).attr("ows_Created_By")), how can i append it with a profile picture ?